# Laravel Unable to copy contents of one database into another

Tags: php, laravel

I'm not sure how to go about this. I have a working table that I manipulate data on to match the rest of our database, and a published table that I want to transfer the finalized data onto. Although `truncate()` performs and clears out the `Report` table, the `Prescription` table remains empty after this runs. Is this some sort of Eloquent issue that I'm not understanding?

Here is my code:

```
// call working table
$reports = Report::orderBy('id', 'asc');

// loop through every working report and save as a new prescription
foreach ($reports as $report) {
    $prescription = new Prescription();
    $prescription->script_id = $report->script_id;
    $prescription->medication = $report->medication;
    $prescription->fill_date = $report->fill_date;
    $prescription->type = $report->type;
    $prescription->quantity = $report->quantity;
    $prescription->supply = $report->supply;
    $prescription->insurance = $report->insurance;
    $prescription->rx_number = $report->rx_number;
    $prescription->copay = $report->copay;
    $prescription->tr = $report->tr;
    $prescription->cogs = $report->cogs;
    $prescription->fees = $report->fees;
    $prescription->ncr = $report->ncr;
    $prescription->save();
}

// truncate working table
$reports->truncate();

// return
$message = 'All records transferred to prescriptions table.';
return redirect('reports')->with('success', $message);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `->get()` on your Report query, to actually retrieve the results. As it is, `$reports` only contains the query builder object.

```
$reports = Report::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
```

You'll most likely need to adjust the truncate call afterwards:

```
Report::truncate();
```